# Diferença entre consultas MySQL - Delphi

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, delphi

Boa tarde, estou fazendo rotina pra fechamento do inventário tanto no SPED como Sintegra, porém está dando diferença no somatório dos dois. Estou usando data como referência 31/12/2018.
Estou usando a mesma consulta mas de formas diferentes, no qual o valor correto seria o do sintegra, e do sped está dando a mais, onde será que estou errando? Segue meus códigos:

CÓDIGO DO SINTEGRA:

```
procedure TFSintegraTela.PopulaCDSEstoqueRegistro74(pDataFim: TDate);
var
    SQL, DataEstoque : String;
begin
    CDSEstoque.Filtered := False;
    CDSEstoque.Filter := '';
    DataEstoque := FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd',pDataFim);

    SQL := 'SELECT M.ID_PRODUTO,A.NOME_PRODUTO, A.NCM, SUM(M.QUANTIDADE) AS QTDADE, SUM(M.VALOR_TOTAL) AS CUSTO_TOTAL, '+
    '(SUM(M.VALOR_TOTAL) / SUM(M.QUANTIDADE)) AS CUSTO_UNI, B.SIGLA AS UND '+
    'FROM movimento_produto M '+
    'INNER JOIN produto A ON (A.ID = M.ID_PRODUTO) '+
    'INNER JOIN unidade_produto B ON (B.ID = A.ID_UNIDADE) '+
    'WHERE (M.DATA_MOVIMENTO <= '+QuotedStr(DataEstoque)+') '+
    'GROUP BY M.ID_PRODUTO ORDER BY A.NOME_PRODUTO;' ;

    QueryEstoque.Close;
    QueryEstoque.SQLConnection := TDBExpress.getConexao;
    QueryEstoque.SQL.Text := SQL;
    QueryEstoque.Open;
    CDSEstoque.Active :=True;
    CDSEstoque.First;

    if RadioEstoques.ItemIndex = 0 then
    begin
        CDSEstoque.Filtered := False;
        CDSEstoque.Filter := 'QTDADE > 0';
        CDSEstoque.Filtered := True;
    end
    else
        CDSEstoque.Filtered := False;
    end;
end;
```

Ao final ele me retorna:
Rows: 5;396
Valor total do inventário: 623.837,97

CÓDIGO DO SPED:

```
procedure PopulaCDSBlocoH(pDataFim: TDate);
var
    SQL, DataEstoque: String;
    cdsTemp: TClientDataSet;
begin
    CDSEstoque := TSQLQuery.Create(nil);
    DataEstoque := FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd', pDataFim);

    SQL := 'SELECT M.ID_PRODUTO, A.NOME_PRODUTO, A.NCM, SUM(M.QUANTIDADE) AS QTDADE, ' +
   'SUM(M.VALOR_TOTAL) AS CUSTO_TOTAL, '+
   '(SUM(M.VALOR_TOTAL) / SUM(M.QUANTIDADE)) AS CUSTO_UNI, B.SIGLA AS UND '+
   'FROM movimento_produto M '+
   'INNER JOIN produto A ON (A.ID = M.ID_PRODUTO) '+
   'INNER JOIN unidade_produto B ON (B.ID = A.ID_UNIDADE) '+
   'WHERE (M.DATA_MOVIMENTO <= '+QuotedStr(DataEstoque)+') '+
   'AND M.QUANTIDADE > 0 GROUP BY M.ID_PRODUTO ORDER BY A.NOME_PRODUTO';

   CDSEstoque.SQLConnection := TDBExpress.getConexao;
   CDSEstoque.SQL.Text := SQL;
   CDSEstoque.Open;
   CDSEstoque.First;

end;
```

Ao final ele me retorna:
Rows: 6.996
Valor total do inventário: 1.449,628,17

Answer (score 2):

Simplificando as duas `queries` temos o seguinte:

```
SELECT M.ID_PRODUTO,
       A.NOME_PRODUTO,
       A.NCM,
       SUM(M.QUANTIDADE) AS QTDADE,
       SUM(M.VALOR_TOTAL) AS CUSTO_TOTAL,
       SUM(M.VALOR_TOTAL) / SUM(M.QUANTIDADE) AS CUSTO_UNI,
       B.SIGLA AS UND
  FROM movimento_produto M
 INNER JOIN produto A ON A.ID = M.ID_PRODUTO
 INNER JOIN unidade_produto B ON B.ID = A.ID_UNIDADE
 WHERE M.DATA_MOVIMENTO <= :DATAESTOQUE
 GROUP BY M.ID_PRODUTO
 ORDER BY A.NOME_PRODUTO;


SELECT M.ID_PRODUTO,
       A.NOME_PRODUTO,
       A.NCM,
       SUM(M.QUANTIDADE) AS QTDADE,
       SUM(M.VALOR_TOTAL) AS CUSTO_TOTAL,
       SUM(M.VALOR_TOTAL) / SUM(M.QUANTIDADE) AS CUSTO_UNI,
       B.SIGLA AS UND
  FROM movimento_produto M
 INNER JOIN produto A ON A.ID = M.ID_PRODUTO
 INNER JOIN unidade_produto B ON B.ID = A.ID_UNIDADE
 WHERE M.DATA_MOVIMENTO <= :DATAESTOQUE
   AND M.QUANTIDADE > 0
 GROUP BY M.ID_PRODUTO
 ORDER BY A.NOME_PRODUTO;
```

A diferença dos dois é a comparação do `WHERE` `M.QUANTIDADE > 0`. Então o que podemos concluir é que talvez haja alguns registros com o campo `QUANTIDADE` `NULL` ou `0`.

Answer (score -1):

Eu acho confuso esse comando sum. Prefiro montar a estrutura e depois dar um loop, armazenando a soma em uma variável.

```
Soma := 0;
While not dataset.eof do
Begin
    Soma ;= soma + campodataset ;
    Dataset.next;
End ;
```